# how to check groups for specific user in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find query which can give me groups a specific user belongs to.
I tried `Exec master.dbo.xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\MYNAME'`

But it doesnt help. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Are you talking about domain groups here, or do you actually mean SQL Server roles?

Comment: @Larnu sql server roles. what permissions i have that i want to check because i get some error that i dont have view definition permission

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check users in a security group in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27101364/2029983) (Note this links to the **second** answer).

Comment: @Larnu yes it works. I heard there is something called as whoami/groups. but couldnt find it